# SSRS Need multiple references to a report item in header

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a text box in the header of my report that has the following expression:

`=IIf(ReportItems!Voided.Value = "V", "**** VOID ****", "")`

So basically if another text box named "Voided" has the value of V, then display **** VOID **** in the header of the report. This works perfectly.

I need to do it this way because sometimes there are multiple records in a report, and using `First(Fields!Voided.Value)` in the header will not work because sometimes one of the records will be voided, and others will not. Using First() will cause inaccuracies.

However, my requirements have changed to now need **** VOID **** to be displayed if Voided = V, and **** VOID - Prior Payroll **** to be displayed iv Voided = X.

It seems SSRS does not like this nested if in the header `=IIf(ReportItems!Voided.Value = "V", "**** VOID ****", IIf(ReportItems!Voided2.Value = "X", "**** VOID Previous Payroll ****", ""))`

because it gives the error `The value for the text run refers to more than one report item. An expression in the page header or footer can only refer to one report item`

Is there a way to display nested IIF type logic in the header based upon a ReportItem in the body of the report?

Comment: you could do this in the report body and hide the column then refer to the single value in your header. Not tried this but it might work.

Comment: Ah, forgot to mention that the VOID should be at the top of every page if the report is multiple pages, so it is needed in the header.

Comment: If you Voided.Value appears in the body it should still work. All we are doing is evaluating your two conditions in the main body but referencing the new hidden text field in the header as your first simple example did (the one that works).

Answer (score 2):

Placeholders to the rescue!! Much thanks to a colleague for this. It seems SSRS allows for creating **two** placeholders within one text box. Each placeholder can have it's own expression!

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]